# Passing value between activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have one activity given below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.academic_lay);
        Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        Academic_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
        Academic_list = new ArrayList<String>(Academic_category.keySet());
        adapter = new AcademicAdapter(this, Academic_category, Academic_list);
        Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                if(Academic_category.get(
                        Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition)=="Department of Economics"){
                    String dpmt="Economics";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Academic_Structure.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Dpmt", dpmt);
                    System.out.println(dpmt);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Another activity where I am receiving the value set for the key "Dpmt"in the first activity is given below:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf_layout);
        System.out.println(getIntent().getStringExtra("Dpmt"));
```

But it is giving the output as null.
Please can anybody help as to how I can get the value as "Economics" for the key "Dpmt" in the second activity.

Comment: The second activity is `TabLayoutActivity`. Also post stacktrace

Comment: `Academic_category.get(
                        Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition)=="Department of Economics"){` use `.equals` to compare strings

Comment: Hi Raghunandan,
I will edit the code using .equals but my real question is after that I am setting the key value for "Dpmt" as dpmt which contains "Economics" as value.
But when I am receiving it in the second activity it is printing as null

Comment: Strings are compared using equals...write it as  Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition).equals("Department of Economics").  == compares references for strings not objects.

Comment: My real question is about passing the value of the key "Dpmt" from activity to another

Comment: u r getting null because the complier in not reading the if loop as it is false..ur code will work after changing the comparison

Comment: Put the stack trace of your crash or let us know exactly which line you getting the NullPointerException

Comment: Your code seems to be alright, can you confirm at what line you are getting the `NullPointerException`

Comment: I am not getting the null pointer exception. I am able to successfully launch the second activity, but when I am trying to print the value of the key "Dpmt" in the second activity 
 System.out.println(getIntent().getStringExtra("Dpmt"));
it showing as null.

Comment: I think you should confirm once again that you are getting null on the same line not anywhere else....because it seems that your code is fine

Comment: Print `getIntent().getExtra("Dpmt")` in your `TabLayoutActivity`

Comment: what is your else condition

Comment: Did you use `Debug` to check that `intent.putExtra("Dpmt", dpmt);
                    System.out.println(dpmt);
                    startActivity(intent);` is executed normally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change `==Department of Economics` into `equals("Department of Economics")`;

Comment: My real question is about how to pass the value of key "Dpmt" from one activity to another???

Comment: @Ankit67 Then why don't you posting complete part of your code or logcats?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
intent.putExtra("Dpmt", dpmt);
```

try with

```
intent.putExtra("Dpmt", dpmt.toString());
```

This is the code for second class

```
public class Academic_Structure extends Activity {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> Academic_category;
    List<String> Academic_list;
    ExpandableListView Exp_list;
    AcademicAdapter adapter;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.academic_lay);
        Exp_list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        Academic_category = DataProvider.getInfo();
        Academic_list = new ArrayList<String>(Academic_category.keySet());
        adapter = new AcademicAdapter(this, Academic_category, Academic_list);
        Exp_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                if(Academic_category.get(
                        Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition).equals("Department of Economics")){
                    String dpmt="Economics";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Academic_Structure.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Dpmt", dpmt.toString());
                    System.out.println(dpmt);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //startActivity(new Intent("com.bbau.ankit.test_splash.TabLayoutActivity"));
                }
                if(Academic_category.get(
                        Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition).equals("Department of History")){
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.bbau.ankit.test_splash.Contactus"));
                }
                if(Academic_category.get(
                        Academic_list.get(groupPosition)).get(
                        childPosition).equals("Department of Political Science")){
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.bbau.ankit.test_splash.Contactus"));
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Inside TabLayoutActivity please try this snippet

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   String dmpt= extras.getString("Dmpt");                
   System.out.println("Dmpt"+dmpt);
} else {
   System.out.println(bundle is null);
}
```

Comment: it is still coming as null

Comment: can you share the complete code inside onChildClick...and also check whether you are calling second activity from anywhere other than this?

Comment: I have shared the code for first activity in your answer

Answer (score 0):

while getting value use this :

```
String dpmt = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName","defaultKey");
```